# QMake failing to use correct compiler

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a very simple .pro file which is basically

```
CONFIG -= qt
HEADERS = $$files($$PWD/src/*.hpp, true);
SOURCES = $$files($$PWD/src/*.cpp, true);
LIBS += -lboost_system
LIBS += -lyaml-cpp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

This works fine.  However, 3 files in 3 different directories give WARNING: Failure to find: (filepath).  Clicking on the filepath in my integrated terminal (using VSCode) opens the file just fine, so I'm not sure why this works.  These files are also, for whatever reason, compiled using QMAKE_CC instead of QMAKE_CXX.  This does not work as they are C++ files requiring the C++14 standard.  I have temporarily fixed this by overwriting the appropriate variables, like so:

```
QMAKE_CC = $$QMAKE_CXX
QMAKE_CFLAGS = $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS
```

However this feels like a very wrong solution.

What is going on here, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the semicolons.  I've been writing too much C++